# $\int \frac{\mathrm{e}^{ax}}{1-x} \;\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

I want to calculate
$$
\int \frac{\mathrm{e}^{ax}}{1-x} \;\mathrm{d}x \;.
$$
I tried to write the Taylor expansion of $1-x$ around zero $1-x = 1+x+x^2+\ldots$ and then to find $\int x^i\mathrm{e}^{ax} \;\mathrm{d}x$ using integration by parts and the sum the resulting series. I was wondering if a simple and other strait-forward solution exists. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have bad news. Observe a substitution, $a(x-1) = u$, $x = u/a + 1$, $dx = du/a$:

$$\int \frac{\exp(ax)}{(1-x)} dx = \int \frac{\exp(u+a)}{-u/a} \frac{du}{a} = -\int \frac{\exp(u)\exp(a)}{u} du = -\exp(a)\int \frac{\exp(u)}{u}du$$

which has (as a special case) the exponential integral, which can't be done in terms of Elementary functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral